# soap UI : how to Authenticate REST API using certificate and user name and use post json request

Tags: json, rest, request, ssl-certificate, soapui

Using soap ui 4.6 ,I need to authenticate rest api using certificate and username/password and then i have to get the session id(cookie) and work with it for other operation.How can i do this? any reference?

Answer (score -1):

I do this manually in order to avoid any unknown cookies and/or "magic" that the session manager might pass along.  Here is my Java RestAssured example and the equivalent SoapUI request headers:

```
response = given().cookie("SESSIONID", "12345").cookie("ABC_123", "abcde").header("CLIENT_ID", "aaa123");
```

In SoapUI set these headers:

```
Name       Value                           Style   Level
CLIENT_ID  aaa123                          HEADER  RESOURCE
Cookie     SESSIONID=12345; ABC_123=abcde  HEADER  RESOURCE
```

i.e. you put all the cookies in correct format in single header called "Cookie".  Standard http stuff, but nobody really gave this answer yet.